# Calculate mean prices of every quarter between a given startdate and enddate?

Tags: r, date, date-range

I need your help one more time as I don't get the correct result by myself.

My data looks somehow like that:

```
product startdate    enddate     city     cost   double
  1    1999-01-03  2001-02-01   Boston      8       0
  2    2000-07-06  2001-11-24   New York   10,5     0
...
```

What I want is a table which shows me the mean cost divided by city and quarter.

What I did so far:

```
df <- read_csv2("mydata.csv")

#subset data
double <- df$double
df2 <- subset(df,double==0)


#date class
startdate <- strptime(df2$startdate,format="%Y-%m-%d")

library(zoo)
quarter <- as.yearqtr(startdate,"%Y-%m-%d")


table <- tapply(cost,list(df2$city,quarter),mean)
```

The table I get could likely look like that:

```
City       2011 Q1 2011 Q2 2011 Q3
New York     10     11,2    11,7
Boston       9       9,5    9,9
```

My problem is that I have a startdate and an enddate. The table shows me the quarters dependent on the startdate.
I now want to get the same table but quarters should include enddates. That means: If startdate is 2006-01-01 and enddate is 2006-08-01 my item was online in quarters 2006 Q1, 2006 Q2, 2006 Q3.
The price of my item is the same for the whole time but when I calculate the mean prices of every quarter the price should be included in every quarter the product has been online.

What I did is changing class of enddate:

```
#enddate , date class
today <- Sys.Date()
df2[["enddate"]][is.na(df2[["enddate"]])] <- today
enddate <- strptime(df2$enddate,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now I've tried several things like working with date intervals and cut date but this did not work at all.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your full solution could look like this. I have used data.table.

Load data in data.table

```
library(data.table)
d <- read.csv("Products.csv")
D <- as.data.table(d)
```

Condition data to handle dates appropriately and compute the fiscal quarter.

```
# Condition data
#   Format date columns to Date objects
D[, ':=' (Date.Start = as.Date(Date.Start, format="%d-%b-%y"),
  Date.End = as.Date(Date.End, format="%d-%b-%y"))][]
#   Compute the no. of quarters from start, end dates
#     Use:
#       getSeriesV() for dates every quarter given start and end dates
#       getQuarterV() for the fiscal quarter given a date
Quarters <- D[, .(getSeriesV(Date.Start, Date.End))]
Quarters <- lapply(Quarters$V1, function(x) unique(getQuarterV(x)))
```

Expand the data.table in long form to include information upon fiscal quarter.

```
Repeats <- sapply(Quarters, length)
Names <- D[, rownames(.SD)]
de <-  d[rep(Names, Repeats),]
De <- as.data.table(de)
De[, ':=' (Date.Start = as.Date(Date.Start, format="%d-%b-%y"),
           Date.End = as.Date(Date.End, format="%d-%b-%y"))][]
De[, Quarters := unlist(Quarters)]
```

Analyze the data for summaries.

```
De[, .(Avg = mean(Cost)), by=c('Product', 'City', 'Quarters')]
```

I started with data

```
Product,Date.Start,Date.End,City,Cost
Apple,1-Jan-16,1-Aug-16,Bangalore,150
Tomato,1-Dec-15,15-Jan-16,Pune,30
Apple,1-Nov-15,1-Jun-16,Bangalore,155
Tomato,1-Jun-16,1-Dec-16,Bangalore,45
Tomato,1-Oct-16,1-Nov-16,Pune,15
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, helped me a lot understanding what I need to do. Unfortunately I get an error when using the seq function. What I did is format my date columns to date objects. When I want to do this next step: Quarters <- D[, .(getSeriesV(Date.Start, Date.End))] an error occurs: [Error in seq.Date(from = start, to = end, by = "3 months") : 'from' must be of length 1.] Don't know how to fix it. My Date.Start object length is 1158 (a startdate for every product) and looks like that: > D$Date.Start
   [1] "2016-06-18" "2013-06-30" "2016-06-28" "2016-06-24" "2014-01-14" ....

Comment: Tim, have you vectorized the `getSeries()` function to get the `getSeriesV()` function? Do this by `getSeriesV <- Vectorize(getSeries)`. Please see if that works.

Comment: My bad, worked out perfect! Still having trouble when doing the next step: de <-  d[rep(Names, Repeats),] My new data frame "de" sets everything to NA?! > str(de)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 4036 obs. of  183 variables:
 $ city                              : chr  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ enddate                       : Date, format: NA NA ...
 $ startdate                     : Date, format: NA NA ...

Comment: I have posted my sample code on github here: https://github.com/sunbee/R-How-To/blob/master/How%20To%20Pivot%20on%20date%20ranges.R. The data are in the file 'Products.csv'. Please see if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Can you check what is in `Names` and `Repeats`? These should be vectors of the same length. The idea is to expand the data table to long form using row names to repeat rows by the number of quarters spanned by dates.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is to expand your table in long form with the additional piece of information (i.e. column) for quarter of the fiscal year. You can then summarize in the way you want with pivots.

To get the year and quarter, use a function like

```
getQuarter <- function(x, first=0, prefix="Q") {
  # x:      Date object 
  # first:  Jan is 0
  # prefix: Affix symbol for quarter, default 'Q' 
  d <- as.POSIXlt(x);
  q <- floor((d$mon-first+1)/3.03)
  q <- paste0(d$year+1900,'-',prefix,q+1, collapse="")
  q
}
```

Try it:

```
start <- as.Date("01-01-16", format="%d-%m-%y")
end <- as.Date("01-09-16", format="%d-%m-%y")
getQuarter(start)   # "2016-Q1"
getQuarter(end)     # "2016-Q3"
```

Then vectorize it like so.

```
getQuarterV <- Vectorize(getQuarter)
getQuarterV(c(start, end))   # "2016-Q1" "2016-Q3"
```

To get all the quarters between start and end dates, use a function like

```
getSeries <- function(start, end) {
  # start:  Date object
  # end:    Date object
  s <- seq(from=start, to=end, by="3 months")
  s <- c(s, end)
  unique(s)
}
```

Try it:

```
getSeries(start, end)     # "2016-01-01" "2016-04-01" "2016-07-01" ..
getSeries(start, start)   # "2016-01-01"
```

Now put it together to get all quarters between two dates.

```
unique(getQuarterV(getSeries(start, end)))   # "2016-Q1" "2016-Q2" "2016-Q3"
```

You can now proceed to integrate this data with your original data and extract the summaries you need.